# What does Limits.getAggregateQueries() represent?

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, limits

Per [the Limits class documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_methods_system_limits), there are a pair of methods for "aggregate queries":

> **getAggregateQueries()**
>
> Returns the number of aggregate queries that have been processed with any SOQL query statement.
>
> **getLimitAggregateQueries()**
>
> Returns the total number of aggregate queries that can be processed with SOQL query statements.

To what limit do these methods refer?  I have checked the [Limits Guide](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf), and I can't find any limits specific to aggregate queries.  In my DE org, `Limit.getLimitAggregateQueries()` returns 300; I can find no relevant limit with a value of 300.  I've used these methods in measuring code that runs SOQL aggregate queries (albeit dynamic queries, via `Database.query()`);  `Limit.getAggregateQueries()` always returns 0, and the queries are always counted by `Limit.getQueries()`.  Does this refer to some limit no longer in use?  Is it documented elsewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly the naming AggregateQueries is very misleading. My first thought was it should be related to a GROUP BY clause - but it seems to be different. I did not try it on my own but found this article could help with the clarification:

https://bartoszborowiec.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/soql-subqueries-and-limits/

Following this article, the limit seems to count subselects at the SELECT clause

```
        select name,
            ( select id, name, Contact__r.Name
            from AccountContacts__r
            where name != null  )
        from Account
```

but not in the WHERE clause

```
        select name            
        from Account
        where id in ( select Account__c from AccountContact__c )
```

Try the complete code

```
@isTest
private class SubqueriesTest {

    @isTest
    static void testQueriesAgainstLimits() {
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getQueries() );
        List<Account> accounts = [
            select name            
            from Account           
        ];
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getQueries() );
    }

    @isTest
    static void testSubqueriesInWhereClauseAgainsLimits() {
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getQueries() );
        List<Account> accounts = [
            select name            
            from Account
            where id in ( select Account__c from AccountContact__c )
        ];
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getQueries() );
    }

    @isTest
    static void testSubqueriesInSelectClauseAgainsLimits() {
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getQueries() );
        List<Account> accounts = [
            select name,
                ( select id, name, Contact__r.Name
                from AccountContacts__r
                where name != null  )
            from Account           
        ];
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getQueries() );
    }          

    @isTest
    static void testSubqueriesAgainsLimits() {
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 0, Limits.getQueries() );
        List<Account> accounts = [
            select name,
                ( select id, name, Contact__r.Name
                from AccountContacts__r
                where name != null  )
            from Account
            where id in (select Account__c from AccountContact__c)
        ];
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getAggregateQueries() );
        System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getQueries() ) ;
    }  

}
```

Comment: Aha!  And now that I know what to search for, I found this in a footnote on the Total Number of SOQL Queries governor limit (emphasis added):  "In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship sub-queries, each parent-child relationship counts as an additional query. These types of queries have *a limit of three times the number for top-level queries*. The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution."  Since the synchronous limit on number of queries is 100, the 300 limit I saw makes total sense.  And +1 for "very misleading"

Comment: I was thinking of that myself. Glad we have some documentation on that. I even checked the limits documentation, but it didn't register with me.