# What is AGGS limit?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits, developer-console, execution-overview

While going through **Execution Overview** in Developer Console, I noticed a new kind of limit, called **AGGS**. It may not be new, but I never paid attention to it. I tried to find out more about it, but no luck. Even in the [governor limits documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), there is no mention of it. Basically there is no limit with 300 count in the whole set of limits.

I highlighted it in the below screenshots:

**From Execution Overview:**

[image]

**In the raw log:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to correspond to the `Limits.getAggregateQueries()` method.

See also: [What does Limits.getAggregateQueries() represent?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65881/what-does-limits-getaggregatequeries-represent)

Cross-referencing with [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join), this limit counts the number of available **`Left Outer Joins`**.

I ran this snippet to confirm:

```
system.debug([
    SELECT 
        (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities),
        (SELECT Name FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
]);
```

[image: AGGS Limit]

Removing either subquery reduced the limit usage accordingly.

Comment: That link to a previous question is helpful. 'Aggregate' queries is indeed a very misleading term for parent-child subqueries. I find it weird that it doesn't count if it's part of a semi-join (and probably anti-joins as well).

Comment: I didn't know that these are counted as aggregate queries. I only think of aggregate soql functions and AggregateResult. Do you now about the 'used so far column'?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you, I'll create a new question for that. Can you please check the hyper link in the answer. Looks like there is no page.